# Xamarin.Forms WebChromeClient

Tags: android, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

---

The point is, I need to do this in Xamarin.Forms:

```
Android.Webkit.WebView teste = FindViewById<Android.Webkit.WebView>(Resource.Id.navigation);
            teste.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            teste.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            teste.LoadUrl("url");
```

butI  using Xamarin.Forms, any one knows how to do this?

Just to explain, I try to create WebView in Xamarin.Forms that use the chrome and no the native browser to view my WebSite.
Please, if any can help with example!

Answer (score 6):

I just took a look at the WebViewRenderer implementation and it seems like the Xamarin.Forms WebViewRenderer is also using a normal WebChromeClient.

You can look for yourself [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/WebViewRenderer.cs) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/FormsWebChromeClient.cs).

So your problem seems to be another one.